# Making Wheelchart but becomes color fail

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

When I compile this it comes with an error not knowing the colors. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,wheelchart}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    data=,
    radius={1}{4.5},
    slices arc={1}{0.66},
    slices style=\WCvarA,
    start half,
    value=1,
    wheel data={%
        \textbf{Number \WCcount}\\%
        \WCvarB%
    },
    wheel data pos=0.5,
    wheel data style=White
    ]{%
        Yellow/Some text A,
        Orange/Some text B,
        Red/Some text C,
        Green/Some text D,
        Blue/Some text E%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is because the color names `White`, `Yellow` and so on are not defined, unlike the color names `white`, `yellow` etc. Change all color names to lowercase and it should work. If you load the `wheelchair` package, there is no need to load the `tikz` package separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example from the documentation of the wheelchart package, which I wrote. The solution is to give `dvipsnames` as an option to `\documentclass`, as stated in the first section Usage. Thus `\documentclass[border={0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm},dvipsnames]{standalone}`. Also, it is unnecessary to load the package `tikz` because `wheelchart` already loads it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not see that in the first section, stupid me...

Answer (score 2):

By default, `tikz` (which is used by the `wheelchart` package) loads the `xcolor` package without special options, so only the default colours are available. If you want to use additional colour sets, you can load the `xcolor` package yourself with the desired options:

```
\documentclass[border={0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm}]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wheelchart}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \wheelchart[
    data=,
    radius={1}{4.5},
    slices arc={1}{0.66},
    slices style=\WCvarA,
    start half,
    value=1,
    wheel data={%
        \textbf{Number \WCcount}\\%
        \WCvarB%
    },
    wheel data pos=0.5,
    wheel data style=White
    ]{%
        Yellow/Some text A,
        Orange/Some text B,
        Red/Some text C,
        Green/Some text D,
        Blue/Some text E%
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```